# Getting error not connected to the kde-frameworks-5-plug content when trying to run kdenlive

Tags: 20.04, kdenlive

I recently bought a new ubuntu based laptop , I installed kdenlive but when I run the kdenlive command I get this error

```
Error: not connected to the kde-frameworks-5-plug content interface.
```

I have tried to connect kdenlive to kde-frameworks-5-plug as shown below:

```
 sudo snap connect kdenlive:kde-frameworks-5-plug kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-slot
```

but throws this error

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Connect kdenlive:kde-frameworks-5-plug to kde-frameworks-5:kde-frameworks-5-slot (connection not allowed by slot rule of interface "content")
```

can anyone please tell me how can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with snap refresh by

```
sudo snap refresh
```

and then run

```
sudo snap connect kdenlive:kde-frameworks-5-plug kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20:kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20-slot
```